# Laravel 5.8: parse_url() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8, parse-url

I want to insert some data into the DB like this via Eloquent:

```
public function postDarkhast(Request $request)
    {
        RequestTable::create([
            'course_name' => 1,
            'course_start' => 2,
            'course_end' => 3,
            'course_sessions' => 4,
            'course_time' => 5,
            'course_members' => 6,
            'course_mentor' => 7,
            'course_samaneh' => 8,
        ]);
        
        Session::flash('darkhastSubmitted','Request submitted');
        
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

But I don't know why I get this error:

**parse_url() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given**

I don't know where this `parse_url()` comes from and the reason behind this error.

So if you know, please help me out solving this issue?

Here is also the Model `RequestTable`:

```
class RequestTable extends Model
{
    protected $table = "requests";
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

And the fields of `requests` table has this config:

```
varchar(191)    utf8_general_ci   NULL
```

---

**UPDATE #1:**

I put the `RequestTable::create([...]);` in a Try.. Catch and this error return:

[image]

Comment: can you share the your modal code, I wanna make sure that have added guarded?

Comment: @MiteshRathod I just added it, please revisit the question

Comment: your code looks workable!!!
after redirection in which function call?

Comment: @MiteshRathod The return redirect()->back(); does not execute. I put the RequestTable::create([...]); in a Try.. Catch and the result is **#message: "parse_url() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"**

Comment: @MiteshRathod I just updated the question and added a capture of screen

Comment: Did you try replace `return redirect()->back()` to `return back();`?

Comment: It looks like you are importing a different `Request`, Have you imported Request at the top like: `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` ? I believe you are importing this `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are importing the`Request` from Symfony's `HttpFoundation` instead of `Illuminate`. Please try importing the Request at the top like: `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`.

Looking at your error, I believe you are importing the `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` instead.

Comment: Your code seems fine than, there should be an issue in a different part. Can I see your controller and model code fully? Or at least the parts you are importing these.